# Prove $\sin(kx) \rightharpoonup 0$ as $k \to \infty$ in $L^2(0,1)$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

> I want to show that $u_k(x)= \sin(kx) \rightharpoonup 0$ as $k \to \infty$ in $L^2(0,1)$.

We know trivially that $0 \in L^2(0,1)$.

I need to show that $\langle u^*,\sin(kx) \rangle \to \langle u^*, 0 \rangle$ for each bounded linear functional $u^* \in L^2(U)$, where $L^2(U)$ is a dual space of itself (since $L^2$ is a Hilbert space).

I think I need to show that, as $k \to \infty$,

$$\int_0^1 u^* \sin(kx) \, dx \to 0.$$

Comment: You think  $\int_0^1 \sin^2 (kx)\,dx \to 0?$

Comment: No, you're not asked to prove this. Because it's wrong. You have   $\langle u^*, \sin(kx) \rangle \to 0$ without having $\| u^* \sin(kx) \|_2 \to 0$

Comment: @Tryss I'm asked to show $\sin(kx) \rightharpoonup 0$ weakly as $k \to \infty$. What should I do in this case? I took the definition of weak convergence from the Appendix of my textbook.

Comment: You need to show that for every $u^*$, $$\int_0^1 u^* \sin(kx) dx \to 0$$

Comment: Is $\langle u^*, \sin(kx)\rangle$ not correct because that gives the indefinite integral $$\langle u^*, \sin(kx)\rangle=\int u^* \sin(kx) \, dx$$ And we only have the interval $(0,1)$ to begin with.

Comment: @Tryss I don't know if that was true or not, but in any case, how do I integrate $$\int_0^1 u^* \sin(kx) \, dx$$ because $u^*$ is in the way.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato On the duplicate question page, it seems they moved the functional out of the integral. Can I do that here, like $\int_0^1 u^* \sin(kx) \, dx = u^*\int_0^1 \sin(kx) \, dx$?

Comment: By the way, just wondering: How were you able to find a question similar to this, which prompts you to call this question a duplicate? That other question could very well be buried under millions of other questions.

Comment: @dragon There's a search bar. To help that, a lot of common problems have names that are familiar to people who have seen them before. For instance this result follows from any of a number of named results in Fourier analysis, such as the Bessel inequality or Parseval's identity. It is also closely related to the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Answer (score -1):

Let $f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin (2\pi i \,n x) + b_n \cos (2\pi i \,n x) \in L^2[0,1]$ then we have [Bessel inequality](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~peirce/M257_316_2012_Lecture_16.pdf):

$$ \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n^2 + b_n^2) < \bigg|\bigg|\int_0^1 f(x)^2 \, dx\bigg|\bigg|^2 < \infty$$

Then the Fourier coefficients tend to zero $|a_n| =|\langle f ,\sin (2\pi i \,n x)\rangle | \to 0$

---

Any orthogonormal basis tends the intuition here is that $\{ \sin kx \}$ or $\{e^{2\pi i \, kx}\}$ oscillate so violently we may as well just substitute $0$ there.  [Weak convergence](http://math.stanford.edu/~elgart/175/handout.pdf) formalizes this asymptotic behavior in many cases.

Comment: What does "Any orthogonormal basis tends the intuition here is" mean? Is it a typo?